# swift activityViewController send pdf

Tags: swift, pdf, uiactivityviewcontroller

How can i save my pdf stored in my iphone to ibooks with activityController?

My code is `        pageSize = CGSizeMake (850, 1100)

```
    let fileName: NSString = "Cars.pdf"

    let path:NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

    let documentDirectory: AnyObject = path.objectAtIndex(0)

    let pdfPathWithFileName = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName as String)

    self.generatePDFs(pdfPathWithFileName)

    //lines written to get the document directory path for the generated pdf file.

    if let documentsPath = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first?.path {

        print(documentsPath)

let File  = [documentDirectory]
let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: File, applicationActivities: nil)
            presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`
```

but it only shows the documentDirectory in a mail.. i need something to say.. hey there is a pdf file...

Comment: i found the solution.. let paths = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
            let filePath = paths[0].URLByAppendingPathComponent("Cars.pdf")
            
            let File  = [filePath]
            let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: File, applicationActivities: nil)
            presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)